# UWP.C++.PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged Register for My Events

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile, c++-cx

how we can PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged **Register for My Events in C++** ?
I can make a DIRECT Phone call, but when call is not active i need to exit my App.

```
PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged += PhoneCallManager_CallStateChanged;
private async void PhoneCallManager_CallStateChanged(object sender, object e)
{
if (callCame &&(!PhoneCallManager.IsCallActive))
{
//do something
}
if (PhoneCallManager.IsCallIncoming)
{
callCame = true;
}
}
```

something like this ? i need a little Assistance.

```
_taskCompletionToken = _deviceUseBackgroundTaskRegistration->Completed::add(
ref new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(
this, &Scenario1_DeviceUse::OnBackgroundTaskCompleted));
```

Comment: So, your question is just how to register this event in c++ , right ?

Comment: Hi, CoCalceDew, THX,  YES, and i found the GUIDE-LINE: phoneCallManager->CallStateChanged += (Press Tab to insert)  :-----))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have convert above code csharp code to c++ like following.

```
PhoneCallManager::CallStateChanged += ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Platform::Object^>(this, &App8::MainPage::OnCallStateChanged);
bool callCame;
void App8::MainPage::OnCallStateChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ args)
{
    if (callCame && (!PhoneCallManager::IsCallActive))
    {
        //do something
    }
    if (PhoneCallManager::IsCallIncoming)
    {
        callCame = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, CoCalceDew, THX, GUIDE-LINE:  // 1.PhoneCallManager^ phoneCallManager;
 //2.phoneCallManager->  (select CallStateChanged)
 //3.phoneCallManager->CallStateChanged += (Press Tab to insert)

Comment: Hi, it WORKS WELL, but when IsCallIncoming....WHO IS CALLING ? Sender/Args = NULL !